# jQuery Recursive get wait for result

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, get

I am trying to write a recursive function using jQuery to call a php file which sends out emails. The email server sends out batches of 10 emails at a time and I want the JS to keep issuing a GET until data.Finished == true.

My code is as follows:

```
function emailDespatchNotification() {
  $.get('email.php', function(event) {
    if (event.action.status == 'OK') {
      if (event.data.Finished != true) {
        emailDespatchNotification();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The JSON result is as follows:

```
{
"log": {"SQL":{"0":"SELECT ...","1":"INSERT INTO ..."},"0":"Cache cleared","Page":"email.php","Script_Time":3.4495},
"data": {"Finished":false},
"action": {"status":"OK"},
"readable": {}
}
```

When `emailDespatchNotification()` is called for the first time the code behaves as I want it to sending one GET to the server, but when the result (containing data.Finished = false) is returned the JS continuously sends GET requests to the server until I stop it or the browser reports an error.

I do not understand why `emailDespatchNotification()` is being called continuously as it should only be called once the GET has returned a value. I have tried nesting the whole GET into a named function and calling that instead of `emailDespatchNotification()` but it had no effect. I have got around this kind of problem before using lists but I do not know how many times I need to call the server so lists are not appropriate. I am using jQuery 1.8.3 and debugging with Firebug.

Comment: @Joe His code is in the ajax callback like it should be, I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Have you verified the result of the ajax call(s) to make sure it's what you're expecting? It might be helpful to put a breakpoint on the line that calls `emailDespatchNotification();` and check your event object.

Comment: I have verified the ajax result and run it through JSONLint, I have added a sample result into my question.

Comment: Looks like your logic is ok to me: http://jsfiddle.net/qLzDu/. Is the request simply returning very quickly? Is `Finished` ever getting set to true?

Comment: Each request takes just under 4 seconds to complete and the execution time is reported in the JSON. But once the first request is completed and `emailDespatchNotification();` is called, it keeps being called although the php takes 4 seconds to execute the JS does not wait. Finished will be set to true once all emails have been sent but iv got about 1000 records to cover and im only doing 25 a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have fixed the problem by added in a seed to the GET function, although Cache-Control   was set to no-store, no-cache it was caching the result.

The adapted code is as follows:

```
var seed = new Date() / 1;
$.get('beta/email.php', {seed:seed}, function(event) {
```

This way I ensure I get a live version of the page and my code executes fine.

@Jason P Thanks for all the help!